# How to get average of 6 first elements in a queryset and annotate the value in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models that are something like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class FooStatement(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete.models.CASCADE)
    revenue = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField()
```

What I want to know is what the average is of the FooStatement revenue for the first 6 dates for each Foo object. Is there any way to achieve this?

I was thinking of slicing the first 6 entries (after ordering them), but I cannot seem to get this to work. The statement months all start at different dates so I can't just say that I want all dates that are lesser than 'x'.

I'm almost positive the answer lies somewhere in clever annotation, but I just cannot find it.

Edit: Django version 1.11.6 with a postgres database. There are upwards of 4000 Foo objects and they will keep growing.

Comment: It might be relevant to know what version of django and database are you using, can you update your question with that information?

Comment: How many Foo do you have in database ?

Comment: Made an edit to answer these questions; I guess it would be possible to update my database to include a field for the 6 month average and compute it afterwards; the statements aren't changing after all, but I can't imagine that being the best solution :/

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using is F expressions. Though not an ideal solution, it covers roughly 90% of my statements. I annotate the first month and then select all foostatements that are before a certain date and aggregate the average:

```
qs = Foo.objects.all().annotate(f_month=Min(F('foostatement__date')))
value = qs.filter(foostatement__date__lt=F('f_month')+datetime.timedelta(6*365/12)).aggregate(Avg('foostatement__revenue'))
```

A problem still persists with foostatements that skip a month, but for my purposes I can live with that.